Independent socket.io servers on separate child processes
I've been working with express and socket.io, and have successfully created two different apps that serve clients from a domain. So now I'm interested in having the main page for my domain be a portal for those two apps. The problem I'm running into is that I want the two apps to be child processes that get started by the portal app, but I'm not sure how to give them both their own socket.io servers.
I've looked into forking and clusters. I can get forking to start unique processes, but I don't know how to get forked processes to have their own socket.io servers (which don't necessarily need to communicate with each other, but they do both need an http server to run on?). I'd imagine I could get clustered processes to share the http server, but I don't know how to get them to start unique processes. I feel like this should be a straightforward/common thing to do but I can't find an answer that fits.

I think you need a proxy gateway (nginx) which will route to one or another app, I suggest you to deploy your apps to different containers and have nginx container which will act as gateway and apps router
